# Как сделать панель внизу экрана?

Tags: android, android-layout

У меня очень сложная разметка. Запутался. Как сделать панель ПОД `WebView`. Панель нужна будет для двух кнопок слева и справа, а также `EditText` между ними. Нужен `RelativeLayout`.
Код:

```
   <FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!-- Layout Main -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    >

        <!-- WebView -->

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/refresher"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                tools:context="com.shppandroid1.app.MainActivty"
        >
        <WebView android:id="@+id/wv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            /> 
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<!-- Navigation Drawer-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>




<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/header" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_child"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingLeft="3sp"
            android:paddingRight="3sp"
            android:listSelector="#C2C2C2"
    />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



    <!-- BlackList for Night Mode       -->

     <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/ll_bg"
  >
 </LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: сделайте скриншот, и дорисуйте, куда вы хотите панель.

Comment: И код отформатируйте. Сложно его в таком виде понять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместите webwiew и вашу панель в linearlayout. Для webview ширину и высоту задайте match_parent также определите вес значением 1, панель поместите ниже webview и указывайте значения высоты которое вам необходимо.